# How to iterate through entire JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I wrote this code to parse JSON and its fine, to a point. It just stops producing output part of the way through the file. I did len(data) and it returned 6, which is the number of items it returns. But when I do yield data, all 7000+ lines are printed. So how can this code be changed so it iterates through the entire file? Also, how can I return the minimum and maximum coordinates from the 'paths' list?

```
import os
import json
import pprint as p

def jSonYield():
    n = 0
    os.chdir('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\ArcGIS')
    with open('new_corrs_shapy_FeaturesToJS.json') as datafile:
        data = json.loads(datafile.read())
    datafile.close()
    for line in data:
        n = n + 1
        corr =  data['features'][n]['attributes']['CORRIDOR_C']
        trf =  data['features'][n]['attributes']['TRFPOST']
        frf =  data['features'][n]['attributes']['FRFPOST']
        coords =  data['features'][n]['geometry']['paths']
        yield corr,frf,trf,coords


gen = jSonYield()
for line in gen:
    p.pprint(line)
```

Here is a sample bit of the JSON data:

```
{u'attributes': {u'CORRIDOR_C': u'C000896N',
                            u'FID': 2,
                            u'FRFPOST': 0,
                            u'OBJECTID': 4,
                            u'TRFPOST': 0.392},
            u'geometry': {u'paths': [[[682789.8871999979,
                                       173265.5223999992],
                                      [682791.4069999978,
                                       173246.46599999815],
                                      [682796.4217000008,
                                       172938.67540000007],
                                      [682797.1617999971,
                                       172899.74130000174],
                                      [682798.8253000006,
                                       172790.22789999843],
                                      [682802.0223999992,
                                       172634.72960000113]]]}},
```

Comment: You should start with `n = -1` instead of `0` since arrays are zero-indexed, or move `n = n + 1` to the end of the loop

Comment: No both of those still yield just the first 6 sets of json data

Comment: I think the problem lies in `for line in data`. `data` is a dictionary with keys, not "lines".

Comment: Also, maybe do `json.load(datafile)`. You don't need to explicitly read the file into a string first.

Comment: So would  this do the trick ?: for keys() in data:

Comment: what happens if you do x = json.load(file('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\ArcGIS\new_corrs_shapy_FeaturesToJS.json')) and then print(len(x))? How long is the resulting data?

Comment: for k, v in data.items() is probably what you are looking for

Comment: You also don't need `datafile.close()` if you use `with open() as`. More specifically, it is undefined where you have it in your question, so that should throw an error.

Comment: Ok ive made all those changes mentioned above and its still stopping at 6. I'll do what Wombat has right now and let you know how it goes/

Comment: Well its just throwing these errors when try to do that Wombat: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename

Comment: basically, I think @cricket_007 is onto something, you are trying to iterate over the result of JSON parsing as if it was still a text file. You need to figure out what you are actually iterating over.

Comment: Maybe iterate over the first level in data, such as features?

Comment: That did it!  This change made the difference:    for k, v in data['features']:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to recap from the comments:

First problem:

```
for line in data:
```

`data` is a dictionary with keys, not "lines".

Also, if you use `with open() as datafile:`, you don't need `datafile.close()`. That happens automatically outside the `with` indentation.

In order to iterate over all the keys and values in a dictionary (which is what `data` is), you need to do something like

```
for key, val in data.items():
```

Not sure what `data['features']` is, but if that works for you, then great!